# Moving object head on click in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am newbie on Unity 3d.I have started practising with a snake game. I have to move snake head forward first.If i press any key then the snake should start moving ahead.For its head i have taken simply a cube. 
Here is the code. Please tell me where i am doing mistake.

```
public class SnakeMove: MonoBehaviour {

public bool Move_Up;
public bool Move_Below  ;
public bool Move_Right;
public bool Move_Left;

public body first_body;

public float time_movement = .5F;
public float following_movement;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Move_Up = false;
    Move_Below = false;
    Move_Right = false;
    Move_Left= false;
    following_movement = Time.time + time_movement;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        Move_Up = true;
        Move_Below = false;
        Move_Right = false;
        Move_Left = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        Move_Up = false;
        Move_Below = true;
        Move_Right = false;
        Move_Left = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        Move_Up = false;
        Move_Below = false;
        Move_Right = true;
        Move_Left = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        Move_Up = false;
        Move_Below = false;
        Move_Right = false;
        Move_Left = true;
    }

    if (Time.time > following_movement)
    {
        MoveHead();
    }

}

void MoveHead()
{
    if (Move_Up)
    {
        first_body.move(this.transform);
        this.transform.position += transform.forward *transform.localScale.z;
    }
    if (Move_Below)
    {
        first_body.move(this.transform);
        this.transform.position += -transform.forward * transform.localScale.z;
    }
    if (Move_Right)
    {
        first_body.move(this.transform);
        this.transform.position += transform.right * transform.localScale.z;
    }
    if (Move_Left)
    {
        first_body.move(this.transform);
        this.transform.position += -transform.right * transform.localScale.z;
    }
    following_movement = Time.time + time_movement;
}
}
```

The error is:

> Assets/Scripts/SnakeMotion.cs(92,8): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name `body' could not be found. Are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?

Should have I to make a body script also? N what should be included in that script? Or Can i run without making separate Body script also? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
public body first_body;
```

You declare a variable whose type is **body**, but body is not a built-in variable type such as float or bool.

And in your script, i don't know what you actually want to do with the variable **first_body**, is it the snake body? can you explain more about "first_body"?

Comment: yes i have included that for my practice purpose and i didnt focus on it while i was getting prob in my code.Now my snake is working. Thanx :)